# Separar caracteres dentro de una lista en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Tengo una lista con 1 solo elemento el cual es un String de 2 caracteres, mi objetivo es separar esos 2 caracteres de forma que la lista pase a tener 2 caracteres, no estoy encontrando alternativa para solucionarlo, e visto y probé usar `split()` , pero aun así no conseguí el resultado deseado.

Mi lista es la siguiente:

```
Pila = ['+Z']
```

y la forma en la que deberia quedar es la siguiente:

```
Pila = ['+','Z']
```

¿Cómo podría conseguirlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlos de varias formas, lo más sencillo sería quitarle la lista y quedarlo como un simple `str`. Te dejo algunas.

## Bucle

Lo puedes hacer con un bucle, por ejemplo un `for`. Lo que hace es iterar por cada caracter.

```
Pila = ['+Z']

pila_separada = []
for caracter in Pila[0]: #accedemos al elemento 0, para quitar la lista
    print(caracter)
    pila_separada.append(caracter)
print(pila_separada)
```

**Salida:** `['+', 'Z']`

También te dará lo mismo usando [**Comprensión de Listas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)

```
[caracter for caracter in Pila[0]]
```

## Lista

Al usar `list` Python automáticamente itera por los elementos para crear la lista, por lo que simplemente puedes usar eso en tu `string`

```
list(Pila[0])
```

**Salida:** `['+', 'Z']`

Por supuesto también se puede hacer con `tuple` o `set`

```
tuple(Pila[0])
set(Pila[0])
```

## map con lambda

Puedes usar una función lambda que extraiga cada caracter con `map`

```
list(map(lambda i:i, Pila[0]))
```

**Salida:** `['+', 'Z']`

Answer (score 2):

podrías convertir a otra lista, el valor de la lista actual, podrías probar con algo como esto.

```
Pila = ['+Z']
list1=list(Pila[0])
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, te recomiendo buscar PEP o las reglas de Python, por ejemplo nunca empezar una variable con mayúscula

Segundo, la solución más sencilla seria:

```
Pila = ['+Z']

nueva_Pila = list(Pila[0])

print(nueva_Pila)
```

Saludos